# Make Pandas `df.get()` behave gracefully whether column or row key is incorrect

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe and a function that pulls entries from the dataframe. If the requested entry is not present in the dataframe—whether because the requested column does not exist, because the requested row/index does not exist, or both—I would like to return the string `'entry not found'` instead of an error message.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [12, 13, 14, 15], 'col2': [16, 15, 14, 13]})
```

Ideally, I would like to write my query function as

```
def query(col, idx):
    return df.get(col, idx, 'entry not found')
```

Unfortunately, the `df.get()` method only accepts two arguments, so I came up with the following alternatives.

```
    def query1(col, idx):
        return df[col, idx]
    
    def query2(col, idx):
        return df[col].get(idx, 'entry not found')
    
    def query3(col, idx):
        return df.get(col, 'entry not found')[idx]
    
    def query4(col, idx):
        return df.get(col, 'entry not found').get(idx, 'entry not found')
```

Only `query2` and `query4` work if the user asks for a row that doesn't exist:

```
# User asks for a row that doesn't exist.
query1('col1', 24) # KeyError
query2('col1', 24) # 'entry not found'
query3('col1', 24) # ValueError: 24 is not in range
query4('col1', 24) # 'entry not found'
```

Whereas only `query3` (kind of) works if the user asks for a column that doesn't exist:

```
# User asks for a column that doesn't exist.
query1('col5', 3) # KeyError
query2('col5', 3) # KeyError
query3('col5', 3) # Returns 'r' ( = 4th char of 'entry not found')
query4('col5', 3) # AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How can I obtain the desired behavior? Is there a way to do this without a heavy `try: ... except: ...` block?

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether).

Comment: @MustafaAydın It is customary to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer to encourage participation from diverse time zones.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about using `get` twice:

```
def lookup(col, idx):
    """
    `col` is the column indexer, `idx` is the row indexer.
    """
    return df.get(col, {}).get(idx, "entry not found")
```

First `get` will look for a `col` column:

- if it exists, then it gives `df.col`
- if it doesn't, then it gives a dict `{}` (so the successor `get` can work)

Then second `get` looks for `idx` row:

- if `df.col` is queried with this, essentially returns `df.loc[idx, col`] if it exists
- otherwise entry is not found

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate two `get()`, for the dataframe and the returned series, with default values of empty series and the error message

```
def query(col, idx):
    return df.get(col, pd.Series()).get(idx, 'entry not found')

print(query('col1', 0)) # 12
print(query('col1', 10)) # entry not found
print(query('col5', 0)) # entry not found
print(query('col5', 10)) # entry not found
```